# Correct regex expression for searching with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text file as given below:

```
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:5,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.1 % RH, Light 760
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:7,Temperature 24.4 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 757
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:9,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 764
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:11,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 753
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:13,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.1 % RH, Light 764
time: 2014-5-15 9:12:15,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 759
```

I am writing some code to search for the "time" value from each line in the file and send it to an array, named time. The code is given below:

```
var time=[];

time.push(Number(item.match(/time:(.\d+[.]\d+)/)[1]));
time.toString();                            

document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML=time;
```

However, the time values are not being displayed on the webpage. Is there something wrong with the regex expression in item.match()? I am new to JavaScript and really do not know much about regex in JS. Please help.

Comment: do you actually have values in your `time` array after the call to item.match?

Comment: try `/(time:)([^,]*)(,)/`

Comment: i wrote the innerHTML line to display the time array on the webpage, to check if the values are present there. Nothing is getting displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a regex if the input has uniform format.

Just use *String.substring()* and *String.indexOf()* to extract the time.

For example, you could grab everything from the 6th character to the first comma:

```
var comma = s.indexOf(',');
var time = s.substring(6, comma);
```

Isn't that a little easier to read and maintain?

Comment: I agree, but he will need to use indexOf since the position can vary based on two digits or one digit number

Comment: @jahroy: Thank you so much. It did work the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to be explicit with what you are matching. Also this solution will pull any datetimes from a row, even if the input format changes.

```
var time_regex = /(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})/;

// example
var lines = [
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:5,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.1 % RH, Light 760",
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:7,Temperature 24.4 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 757",
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:9,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 764",
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:11,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 753",
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:13,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.1 % RH, Light 764",
  "time: 2014-5-15 9:12:15,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.2 % RH, Light 759",
];

for (var i in lines) {
  var r = lines[i].match(time_regex);
  console.log(r);
}

// logs
// 2014-5-15 9:12:5 
// 2014-5-15 9:12:7 
// 2014-5-15 9:12:9 
// 2014-5-15 9:12:11 
// 2014-5-15 9:12:13 
// 2014-5-15 9:12:15
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = 'time: 2014-5-15 9:12:5,Temperature 24.3 C, Humidity 20.1 % RH, Light 760';
var params = str.replace('time: ', '').split(',');
var date = new Date(params[0]);
```